# tmpdir in py.test setup_class

Tags: python, pytest

I use **py.test** for testing.

In **setup_class()** I need to use **tmpdir** for my class constructor:

```
class TestMyClass:
    def setup_class(self):
        self.t = MyClass(path=tmpdir)

    def test_test(self):
        assert True
```

And I have an error:

```
NameError: name 'tmpdir' is not defined
```

I can't use `setup_class(self, tmpdir)`.

If I use this code:

```
def test_needsfiles(tmpdir):
    print(tmpdir)
    assert 0
```

It's work, but I need **tmpdir** in my class constructor.

How to do this?

Thanks!

**UPD**

I try to do this:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def constructor(tmpdir):
    _t = MyClass(path=str(tmpdir))
    yield _t

class TestMyClass:

    def test_test(self, constructor):
        pass
```

But I can't use scopes in fixture:

`ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'tmpdir' with a 'module' scoped request object, involved factories`

Answer (score 4):

I do this:

```
class TestMyClass:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, tmpdir):
        self.tmpdir = tmpdir.strpath
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` as @santon suggested, but you want to create a fixture outside `TestMyClass` (like you write in the UPD part), you can try this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def t(tmpdir):
    return MyClass(tmpdir)

class TestMyClass:
    def test_test(self, t):
        assert True
```

If you don't want to return anything in a fixture, but for example go to a temp directory, you can also do:

```
@pytest.fixture
def t(tmpdir):
    os.chdir(str(tmpdir))

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("t")                                                               
class TestMyClass:
    def test_test(self):
        assert True
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module to handle with temporary files and dirs. In setup you can create temp dir with [`mkdtemp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) and delete it at `tearDown` from test class.

```
import shutil, tempfile
import unittest

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    def tearDown(self):
        shutil.rmtree(self.tmp_dir)
```